# How create installer with Visual Studio Express 2013?

Tags: c#, express, visual-studio-2013

I developed a program in C# with Visual Studio Express Edition 2013, and I need to create installer for it.
As it is not possible create a installer project in VS Express (as far as I known) the only way I found was to "publish" it (Properties > Publish > Publish now).
This create an .exe file which seems to be the installer, but the program is not installed under Program Files folder (So, the program assets (pictures, sounds…) can't be used.

How can I create an "standard" installer for my program under Program Files folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question. The OP asked about Visual Studio Express which does not allow extensions.

Comment: You should look at WiX. You won't be able to create an installer with in VS but you can using the command line with a little XML. I would also check out Paraffin. It'll create XML's for your application based on the contents of a directory. WiX Heat command will do this also but does not update an existing file with changes (added files, missing files etc) like Paraffin will.